# Automatically increase &columns upon :vsplit, but not beyond maximum

Tags: autocmd, terminal

I wanted vim to increase its `&columns` automatically when I do a `:vsplit`, so I implemented the advice found here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vim_use/R4gg-YdPHJM

Basically, you add:

```
autocmd WinEnter * if winwidth(0) < 80 | set columns+=80 | wincmd = | endif
```

to `.vimrc`.

However, in terminal vim, I opened 3 windows side-by-side, and the `&columns` increased beyond the size of my terminal.

I tried to do this:

```
if &columns + 79 > $COLUMNS | set columns=$COLUMNS | else | set columns+=79 | endif
```

but it didn't work, saying, "`Number required after =: columns=$COLUMNS`".

How can I get `&columns` to increase but only up to a maximum of the `$COLUMNS` environment variable?

Answer (score 1):

`COLUMNS` is a shell variable, not an environmental variable.

You could do something like this:

**This exports COLUMNS before invoking vim**

```
alias vim='export COLUMNS;vim $*'
```

However, the value of the exported `COLUMNS` variable won't be updated if you resize your terminal window while you are running vim.

Answer (score 1):

**Gets the terminal's columns directly without using an environmental variable**

```
let cols = system('tput cols')
if &columns + 79 > cols | set columns=cols | else | set columns+=79 | endif
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about shell variables vs. environment variables until now.

`set columns=cols` didn't work. It needs to be `execute "set columns=".cols`

Also, just in case someone else is also using tmux like me, instead of `tput cols` I need to do `tmux display-message -p "#{pane_width}"`